# Run Geth with a configuration file

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten, nodes, geth-debugging, configuration

I've created a config.toml for Ropsten (NetworkId =3) that looks like this:
https://pastebin.com/raw/2DxWE1jf

But when I run

```
geth --config /home/path-to-config
```

From the cli I get: (Note ChainID:1, should be 3)

```
INFO [08-27|00:10:34.285] Initialised chain configuration config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Constantinople: 7280000 Petersburg: 7280000 Istanbul: 9069000, Muir Glacier: 9200000, YOLO v1: <nil>, Engine: ethash}"
```

And the clients is stucked looking for peers.

What I'm missing? If I run `geth --testnet` it works fine.

In Geth the configuration file works differently from bitcoin/parity?

I've also tried to dump the config file from `geth --testnet`, that works, but if I delete the chaindata I have the same problem. I need to pass the configuration file on the **first** run of the node

Comment: Seems an issue to me, take a look at this: 

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29063/geth-config-file-documentation

I've also searched a relative issue on geth git, but without success, if you can't figure out a solution, maybe you should open it.

Comment: I was thinking the same, as far as I understood the point is that --testnet does not exist in the configuration options so you can specify the networkid (3) but the client will alway start with the mainet genesis file. To solve this you would need write the genesis block in the config.toml but this is not what I'm looking for since the genesis may change in the future. I'll open an issue on github

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the `--ropsten` parameter

```
geth --ropsten --config /home/path-to-config
```

If for some reason you don't want to use the ropsten parameter, follow the instructions below.

1. dump the ropsten config with `geth --ropsten dumpconfig > ropsten_config.toml`
2. change `ropsten_config.toml` at your will, I suggest to change the `datadir`
3. dump the ropsten genesis with `geth --ropsten dumpgenesis > ropsten_genesis.json`
4. init the chain `geth --config ropsten_config.toml init ropsten_genesis.json`
5. start the chain `geth --config ropsten_config.toml`

If ropsten is resetted for some reason:

6. download the new geth client (it will have the new genesis embedded)
7. remove the levelDB and ancient DB with: `geth --config ropsten_config.toml removedb`
8. repeat from step 1)